# Select first visible cell of new row in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, .net-2.0

I'm trying to focus input and fire the editing event on each new row that I add to a DataGridView in my form.

This is the code I am trying to user to achieve this.

```
Private Sub grd_GoldAdders_RowsAdded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs) Handles grd_GoldAdders.RowsAdded
        Dim grid As DataGridView = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)

        grid.ClearSelection()

        If grid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("grid_flag").FormattedValue = Constants.[New] Then

            For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In grid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells
                If Not cell.Visible Then Continue For
                grid.CurrentCell = cell 
                grid.BeginEdit(False)
                Exit For
            Next

        End If

    End Sub
```

The "grid_flag" is a hidden cell which is used to store custom states for a row.

Prior to adding a row, this is what we see on the form: 
[image: Before we add a new row.]

This is what we see when we actually try and add a new row:
[image: Row Add button clicked.]

Notice that both the column 0,0 and the first visible column of the new row are selected, but the column 0,0 has the focus.  I do not wish for 0,0 to either get selected or have the focus.  I also see here that the row indicator is pointing at row 0 too...

This is how I would like to see things after clicking my Add button:
[image: Desired outcome from clicking the Add button.]

Does anyone know where I am going wrong with the code? I've searched SO for the most part of the day trying to solve this one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using your DataGridView's RowAdded event to set the CurrentCell, add the following code wherever you're adding a new record to your DGV (in your Add button's Click event I assume):

```
''# Add the new record to your Data source/DGV.

For Each row As DataGridViewRow In grd_GoldAdders.Rows
    If row.Cells("grid_flag").FormattedValue = Constants.[New] Then 
        grd_GoldAdders.CurrentCell = row.Cells("AssySiteColumn")  ''# I'm calling the first column in your DGV 'AssySiteColumn'.
        grd_GoldAdders.BeginEdit(False)
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

This code simply loops through all the rows in your DGV and specifies as the CurrentCell the first cell in the first row with your `Constants.[New]` flag value.

Comment: This wont work if the rows are sorted as the last row (numerically) in the grid may not be the last row (chronologically) to of been added.

Comment: @Mike This is true - I edited my answer to handle this case. There are other ways to do what you need to do, but to explore them you'll have to provide more detail.